# Date filter is not working,Filtering between the dates,getting from-date and to-date from the user

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

Filtering between the dates is not working,getting from-date and to-date from the user

views.py

```
def select_date(request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    fromdate = request.POST.get('fromdate')
    todate = request.POST.get('todate')
    print(fromdate)
    print(todate)
    pdf = Client_files.objects.filter(Date__date__range=(fromdate, todate))
    print(pdf)
    if request.method == "POST":
        fromdate = request.POST.get('fromdate')
        todate = request.POST.get('todate')
        return render(request,'select_date.html', {'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process,'fromdate':fromdate,'todate':todate})
```

Comment: What form did you use to query data from the user?

Comment: by using html date field,getting data from the user <div>
                                    <label>From </label>
                                    <input type="date" class="txtDate form-control" name="fromdate">
                                  

                                </div><br>  <label>To </label>
                                    <input type="date" class="txtDate form-control" name="todate">
                                </div>